# How organize asynchronous codes with Dojo?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, asynchronous, dojo, restful-url

I am creating a webapp with dynamic TABs (data from RESTful) and each TAB has a dgrid, which I get the columns from a RESTful and the rows from a RESTful, as well. I made everything works well with XHR and MemoryStore, but I now need to change from XHR to JsonRest, because I need to pass to  the server, a HTTP Range.

I am having dificulties to organize my code with Asynchronous calls in Dojo. I will give you an example:

```
method1() - Sync 
method2() - Async (JsonRest) 
method3() - Sync
```

What the best way for the method3() be executed, only after method2() is ready?

I have found a class called WHEN. It seems nice. But how do you work with Async apps in dojo?

My biggest problem now: I can't separate my codes by methods, I need put all my code inside the JsonRest's promise function(THEN). Because inside THEN I can't access another method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would concur with the recommendation of using Dojo's promise implementation.

This might help you make some sense of it faster if you are not used to promises: http://jsfiddle.net/27jyf/9/. Another nice feature of this is error handling, I would encourage you to read on this after you have the basic sequencing down.

```
require(["dojo/Deferred", "dojo/when"], function(Deferred, when) {
    var sayHello = function() { return 'hello' };
    var sayWorld = function() {
        var deferred = new Deferred();        
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            deferred.resolve('world');
        }, 1000);        
        return deferred.promise;
    };
    var sayBang = function() { return '!' };

    //This will echo 'hello world !'
    //That's probably how you want to sequence your methods here
    var message = [];
    message.push(sayHello());
    sayWorld().then(function(part) {
        message.push(part);
        message.push(sayBang());
        console.debug(message.join(' '));
    });    

    //This will also echo 'hello world !'
    //This probably not the syntax that you want here, 
    //but it shows how to sequence promises and what 'when' actually does
    var message2 = [];
    when(sayHello())
    .then(function(part) {
        message2.push(part);
        return sayWorld();
    })
    .then(function(part) {
        message2.push(part);
        return when(sayBang());
    })
    .then(function(part) {
        message2.push(part);
        console.debug(message2.join(' '));
    }); 

    //Provided the behavior observed above, this will echo 'hello !'
    //dojo/when allows you to use the same syntax for sync and async... 
    //but it does not let you magically write async operations in a sync syntax
    //'world' will be pushed into the array a second later, after the message has already been echoed
    var message3 = [];
    message3.push(sayHello());
    when(sayWorld(), function(part) {
        message3.push(part);
    });
    message3.push(sayBang());
    console.debug(message3.join(' '));
});
```

Comment: note that JsonRest actually uses the promise API itself.  So you can use var promise = myJsonRest.get();

promise.then(function(){/*my success behavior */}, function() {/*my failure behavior*/});

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [promise api](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/promise.html) to run async/sync methods in a specified order.